# Can't run installer with wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine

I'm trying to play a game called "Rift" on Ubuntu using wine. In order to run "Rift" you have to run something called "Glyph" to play it. I'm trying to run the Glyph installer using wine and I get the window provided below:

[image: "Glyph installation" window]

I tried just leaving it alone instead of clicking "ok", but it will not install glyph. That window just stays there until I either click the x or until I click "OK". How can I get Glyph installed?

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22884 seems to indicate that installing vcrun2012 through winetricks may help Glyph run successfully. (Installing both vcrun2012 and the game through PlayOnLinux would be another option)

Answer (score 0):

"Wine is a free implementation of Windows on Unix", that's what wine all about.
so you may say that you're running Windows on you machine, that requires you to install important programs to run any Windows game (as we do in Windows).
to be more specific you most install (Visual C++ Runtime..,DirectX etc...)